# Storing Exception.ToString() in a database column

Tags: c#, exception, tostring

I've read at multiple locations that using .ToString() on Exception object gives more information when compared to .Message().

However in my case, I want to persist as much information as I can in a column in database for which I am using nvarchar(max) column. I am seeing that my exception detail in this column is being truncated to 256 chars. Am I missing something?

Comment: What database are you using? How are you inserting it? What happens if you try inserting something else that is longer than 256 characters, e.g. `new String('a', 1000)`?

Comment: Which database server are you using? Let's also see the code you're using to store the data. Quite possibly something other than the database is limiting the column size.

Comment: It was somewhere in the pipeline for inserting the data into DB that I was using NVarChar(256). Turns out a silly bug from my side. Thanks all for help and replies.